# Changing CSS Module variables with Next JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get the colors of this page generate randomly each time someone loads in or refreshes the page and I need to avoid referencing impure CSS classes. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

## index.js

```
import styles from '../styles/sliderpage.module.css'

import Head from 'next/head'

import './api/mouseListener'
import './api/colorChange'

export default function Home() {
return (
     <div class={styles.slide_wrap}>
       <div class={styles.main}>
         <Head>
           <title>Title of Website</title>
           <meta name="description" content="Site under construction." />
           <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" />
         </Head>
         <div id="left-side" class="side">
           <h2 class="title">
             Company name <br />will
             <span class="fancy"> brb.</span>
           </h2>
         </div>
         <div id="right-side" class="side">
           <h2 class="title">
             Company name <br />will
             <span class="fancy"> brb.</span>
           </h2>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   )
 }
```

## colorChange.js

```
if (typeof window === "object") {
function random(min,max) {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;
    return num;
  }

function randomColor() {
    return `rgb(${random(0, 255)}, ${random(0, 255)}, ${random(0, 255)})`;
  }

const stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];
const slideWrapper = [...stylesheet.cssRules].find((r) => r.selectorText === "slide_wrap");

function setRandomColor() {
    const newColor = randomColor();
    slideWrapper.style.setProperty('--c1', newColor);
    slideWrapper.stlye.setProperty('--c2', newColor);
  }
}
```

## sliderpage.module.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Rubik&display=swap');
.slide_wrap {
  --dark: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  
  --c1: rgb(6, 21, 39);
  --c2: rgb(124, 145, 204);
  
  --left-color: var(--c1);
  --right-color: var(--c2);
}

.main {  
  background-color: var(--dark);
  margin: 0px;
}
```

I just want to use the contents of colorChange.js to update the colors stored in the --c1 and --c2 variables of my stylesheet linked and reflect those back on the index page. I am working in nextjs currently. The colors need only update when the page is loaded initially or on refresh.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables_javascript.asp could this help?

Comment: @user20386762 only problem with that is the root tag. Can only reference pure css classes in my use case as far as I know

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't define your css variables in :root?